# Alert Dialog method called on button click but can not show the dialog box

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I am having the issue with the alert dialog box.

When i click on the button in row, method call goes inside the method but the alert box donot appear.

this is my code.

```
 final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this.activity,R.style.MyAlertDialogStyle);
    ImageView img_user_delete=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.img_user_delete);
    img_user_delete.setTag(position);
    img_user_delete.setOnClickListener(new ImageView.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //do something
            name1_u = name_user.get(position);
            Log.e("Row_list_user", "name : " + name1_u);
            final int position = (Integer) v.getTag();
            Integer position1 = position + 1;
            builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete?")
                    .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_warning)
                    .setTitle("Warning")
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            db.deleteUserRow(name1_u);
                            name_user.remove(position);
                            notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            dialog.cancel();

                        }
                    });
        }
    });
```

This code works fine in one class but not working in another class.Please help.

Comment: where you call builder.show() method?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. That is the only reason for it not showing. So silly not to call the show() method. It working fine now,

Comment: Exactly as @Ajinkya says you are not calling show()  and please dismiss the dailog on No as well

Comment: yes she was right,,,it solved the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call `create()` method to create an `AlertDialog` with the arguments supplied to `builder` and `show()`method to show `AlertDialog`. See the code below:

```
final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this.activity, R.style.MyAlertDialogStyle);
        ImageView img_user_delete = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.img_user_delete);
        img_user_delete.setTag(position);
        img_user_delete.setOnClickListener(new ImageView.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //do something
                name1_u = name_user.get(position);
                Log.e("Row_list_user", "name : " + name1_u);
                final int position = (Integer) v.getTag();
                Integer position1 = position + 1;
                builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete?")
                        .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_warning)
                        .setTitle("Warning")
                        .setCancelable(false)
                        .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                db.deleteUserRow(name1_u);
                                name_user.remove(position);
                                notifyDataSetChanged();
                            }
                        })
                        .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                dialog.cancel();

                            }
                        }).create().show();
            }
        });
```